# Copy data from previous sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet document where I register tournament results with a sheet for each tournament date. I want to have a cumulative column to show cumulative information. I have already achieved this manually. For Example, on sheet 1, I have the following data:

```
Team     Points   Accum Points  
TeamA    4        4  
TeamB    2        2  
TeamC    1        1
```

On sheet 2, I have this:

```
Team     Points   Accum Points  
TeamA    2        6  
TeamB    1        3  
TeamC    4        5
```

The formula for column "Accum Points" on row 2 of sheet 2 is: 
Sheet1!C2 + B2
The formula for column "Accum Points" on row 2 of sheet 3 is: 
Sheet2!C2 + B2
The formula for column "Accum Points" on row 2 of sheet 4 is: 
Sheet3!C2 + B2

and so on...Each time I add a date, I copy the previous sheet, modifying the columns formula.

I would like to have a "generic" formula for all sheets (except sheet 1) that would be something like

```
[[ActualSheet]-1]!C2 + B2
```

or

```
[PreviousSheet]!C2 + B2
```

Anyone know if this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a custom formula returning the sheet name. See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=3908b38f4b7fb80b&hl=en